# *ngFor directive iterating the same parameter while incrementing the index

Tags: angular

I am facing with a problem in Angular. Basically I am looping in a *ngFor an array and the index.
When I enter in a specific condition I want to iterate the same parameter twice while the index is normally incrementing.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class= "col-md-6" *ngFor="let p2 of params | orderBy: 'positionInGroup'; let i = index">
     <div class="row" *ngIf="!p2.isHidden">
         <!--display something -->
     </div>
     <div class="row" *ngIf="p2.isHidden">
          <!--when is hidden I want to iterate the same p2 of this loop
              while 'i' increments by 1 as usual-->
     </div>
</div>
```

So basically, in that condition, I want to iterate the same parameter p2 twice. How can I do that?

Comment: Something like params[index + 1] solve your problem? If does not solve, can you specify more details?

Comment: That's not how ngFor works. If you want to loop over a transformed version of your iterable, transform it before looping?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to *repeat* `p2` when you find one that is hidden?

Comment: Nope! Basically when, for example I am iterating params at index=1, I face up with p2.isHidden and in the next loop i don't want to iterate the next p2 but the same p2 of this loop while index=2 @LeonardoGetulio

Comment: Yes @Reactgular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngFor is just a looping construction, if you want to transform the data you're looping over you're (much) better off doing that before you start looping in the template. this could be done by adding a property like this and looping over that instead:

```
get transformedParams() {
    result = [];
    for (param of this.params) {
        result.push(param);
        if (param.isHidden) { 
            result.push(param)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

this way the index will increment normally for every unique item in `params` but since every item from `params` is added to `transformedParams` twice, you'll get two iterations with the same object. This should allow you to do what you want without complicated logic in your template.